# How to detect missing parameter route and show relevant message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Working on Laravel 4, I created following route and able to fetch ID:

```
Route::get('details/{ID}', 'Exchange@details');
```

Issue is when I miss ID in route then it shows: NotFoundHttpException error. I want to avoid this. How do I proceed? Even in global.php I added following but did not work:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    print "Not Found";
//  return Response::make(
//      View::make('errors/404')
//  , 404);
});
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function details($exchangeID)
        {
            echo "Print Details";
            echo $exchangeID;
            if(intval($exchangeID) == 0)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException;
            }
        }
```

**Update:** Recommendation of redirecting to 404 works but I am more interested to detect missing ID and load my Own View with proper message information instead of showing plain 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
# file routes.php
Route::get('{ID?}', 'SomeController@getDetails')



# file SomeController.php
function getDetails($ID=null) {
    if empty($ID) {
        return Redirect::to('PREVIOUS PAGE')
            ->withInput()
            ->with('error', 'invalid value');
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws error before reaching to this method. I did something similar. Check updated question.

Comment: Then add a question mark to the parameter to make it optional 

    Route::get('details/{ID?}', 'Exchange@details');

Comment: Great.. this is what I was looking for. I learnt that by *Not* adding `?` I had made it a mandatory parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('errors.404');
});
```

The view is located in views/errors/404.blade.php

Comment: Though it did solve as a workaround but I was more interested to detect missing id and take appropriate action. How to do it? I am accepting your answer though.